# html() does not retrieve the whole content

Tags: ajax, jquery

I am getting the following response

```
<div id="weblogs">
    <tr> 
        <td nowrap class="bl">1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr> 
        <td nowrap class="bl">2</td>
    </tr>
</div>
```

Now I am trying to attach the rows like the following:

```
 function _ajax(postData)
    {       
        loadUrl         = "getweblogs.asp"; 
        $.ajax( {
            url : loadUrl, // your ajax file
            type : 'post',
            data : postData,                
            success : function( resp ) {
                alert($("#weblogs" , resp).html());
                $('#weblogs > tbody:last').append($("#weblogs" , resp).html());

            }
        });
        return false;
    }
```

The replace is working fine. My problem is, that the htmls elements from the response are removed. I'm getting only 1 and 2. instead of

```
   <tr> 
        <td nowrap class="bl">1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr> 
        <td nowrap class="bl">2</td>
    </tr>
```

I don't know what am I doing wrong. Could someone give me any clue?

Thank you!

Greetings 
Magda

Comment: What do you mean saying you are getting only 1 and 2?

Comment: You realised that you don't have a tbody element, didn't you?

Comment: hi karolis,

<tr> 
        <td nowrap class="bl">1</td>
</tr>
gives me 1. there are missing html tags. strictly speaking this part
 <tr><td nowrap class="bl"></td></tr> is missing

Comment: hi felipe,
as i already told, the replace is working fine. i  have tbody in the page. the problem is the .html() function.

Answer (score 2):

What you're trying to do is not so clear. Is there already an element with `id="weblogs"` in the page? If so, why does your response have an element with the same id (not a good idea), and if not, why are you trying to append an element's contents to itself like that (also, not a good idea)?

Why not just change the server-side to send the html required, without a wrapping `div` tag (which makes it invalid html anyway, another bad idea), and then use it as-is?

Another problem is that you're trying to select `.html()` of something that will always be an empty jquery object: `$(selector, string)` will never match anything. You'll need to make the string a jquery object if you want to search its substructure: `string = $(string)`.

And I think you're misunderstanding the use of `$(selector, $obj)`. The selector must be in the `$obj`'s **sub**-structure:

`$('#foo', $('<div id="foo"><span/></div>')); // returns empty jquery object`

So looking for `#weblogs` in the substructure of an element with id `weblogs` will also never find anything.

Comment: hi davin,

thank you for replay. 
1. i have a table with id weblogs.
<table id="weblogs" cellpadding=3 cellspacing=0 bgcolor="#ffffff" border=1 >
2. i want to fill more divs, that why i am wraping everything with div. 
3. the string is matched, but without html tags...

Comment: @Magda, "fill more divs" is not something you can do to a table. A table contains rows, not divs.

Comment: hi davin, 
sorry.. i mean i wanna fill more divs and a table.

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't entirely clear, but I'll try and answer: are you working with Internet Explorer? If so, consider this paragraph from the docs:

> For example, Internet Explorer sometimes leaves off the quotes around attribute values if they contain only alphanumeric characters.

[API docs: html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/)

Comment: hi ben,
thank you for your answer. no, it happends in firefox 4.0.1